# How can I load and app onto my device for testing

Tags: xcode10.2

I just started building and app using Xcode and I wanted to test it on my phone but I get 2 errors on my general tab. I followed the apple tutorial on building my first app but I want to get it on my phone. I am not registered to the apple developer program.

Not tried much as I am new to the iOS programming world

1) Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "com.example.FoodTracker" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

2)No profiles for 'com.example.FoodTracker' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.FoodTracker'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by editing the bundle identifier to something unique.